# impossible to build appbundle

Tags: android, flutter

I updated an app that crashes, and I can't get back to the previous settings. I can't upgrade my app, I have this message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /Users/...  AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
```

Here is my gradle-wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-bin.zip
```

and here is my build gradle

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

If it can help, I have an old version of flutter ( last before null safety 1.22.6)

I try flutter clean, invalidate cache and restart, but no result, I can't even, run a basique flutter example projet

Comment: check out for <queries> Tag in your manifest/ or dependencies Manifest

Comment: Try removing it and rebuild. if it doesn't helps then try updating gradle-wrapper and tools.build:gradle to latest version.

Comment: You should add the contents of your manifest.xml file to the question - the error is telling you that there is a `<queries>` element, and it doesn't recognise it or it's in the wrong place.

Comment: its seems to be ok, due to a <queries> , thank all